# How to query a firestore search for a name within a document?

Tags: javascript, database, api, search, google-cloud-firestore

What i have set up for my firestore database is one collection called 'funkoPops'. That has documents that are genres of funkoPops, with an array of funkoData that holds all pops for that genre. it looks like this below

---

I should also note, that the collection funkoPops has hundreds of documents of 'genres' which is basically the funko pop series with the sub collections of funkoData that I web scraped and now need to be able to search through the array field of 'funkoData' to match the name field with the given search parameter.

```
collection: funkoPops => document: 2014 Funko Pop Marvel Thor Series => fields: funkoData: [ 
{
  image: "string to hold image",
  name: "Loki - with helmet",
  number: "36"
},
{
  image: "string to hold image",
  name: "Black and White Loki with Helmet - hot topic exsclusive",
  number: "36"
},
{
etc...
}
```

So how could i run a query in firestore to be able to search in collection('funkoPops'), search through the document fields for name.

I have the ability to search for genres like so, which gives the genre back and the document with the array of data below:

```
const getFunkoPopGenre = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    console.log(req.params);
    const genre = req.params.genre;
    const funkoPop = await firestore.collection("funkoPops").doc(genre);
    const data = await funkoPop.get();
    if (!data.exists) {
      res.status(404).send("No Funko Pop found with that search parameter");
    } else {
      res.send(data.data());
    }
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).send(error.message);
  }
};
```

what i am trying to use to search by the field name is below and returns an empty obj:

```
const getFunkoPopName = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const name = req.params.name;
    console.log({ name });
    const funkoPop = await firestore
      .collection("funkoPops")
      .whereEqualTo("genre", name);
    const data = await funkoPop.get();
    console.log(data);
    res.send(data.data());
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).send(error);
  }
};
```

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: Hope, the comparison condition on field `name`, so the condition should be .whereEqualTo('name', name). Also in firestore you have to pass the full string value for match and fetch the document.

Answer (score 0):

So the way i went about answering this as it seems from top comment and researching a little more on firebase, you do you have to match a full string to search using firebase queries. Instead, I query all docs in the collection, add that to an array and then forEach() each funkoData. From there i then create a matchArray and go forEach() thru the new funkoData array i got from the first query. Then inside that forEach() I have a new variable in matches which is filter of the array of data, to match up the data field name with .inlcudes(search param) and then push all the matches into the matchArr and res.send(matchArr). Works for partial of the string as well as .includes() matches full and substring. Not sure if that is the best and most efficient way but I am able to query thru over probably 20k data in 1-2 seconds and find all the matches. Code looks like this

```
try {
    const query = req.params.name.trim().toLowerCase();
    console.log({ query });
    const funkoPops = await firestore.collection("test");
    const data = await funkoPops.get();
    const funkoArray = [];
    if (data.empty) {
      res.status(404).send("No Funko Pop records found");
    } else {
      data.forEach((doc) => {
        const funkoObj = new FunkoPop(doc.data().genre, doc.data().funkoData);
        funkoArray.push(funkoObj);
      });
      const matchArr = [];
      funkoArray.forEach((funko) => {
        const genre = funko.genre;
        const funkoData = funko.funkoData;
        const matches = funkoData.filter((data) =>
          data.name.toLowerCase().includes(query)
        );
        if (Object.keys(matches).length > 0) {
          matchArr.push({
            matches,
            genre,
          });
        }
      });
      if (matchArr.length === 0) {
        res.status(404).send(`No Funko Pops found for search: ${query}`);
      } else {
        res.send(matchArr);
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).send(error.message);
  }
```

with a little bit of tweaking, i am able to search for any field in my database and match it with full string and substring as well.

***update***

ended up just combining genre, name, and number searches into one function so that whenver someone searches, the query param is used for all 3 searches at once and will give back data on all 3 searches as an object so that we can do whatever we like in front end:

```
const getFunkoPopQuery = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    console.log(req.params);
    const query = req.params.query.trim().toLowerCase();
    const funkoPops = await firestore.collection("test");
    const data = await funkoPops.get();
    const funkoArr = [];
    if (data.empty) {
      res.status(404).send("No Funko Pop records exsist");
    } else {
      data.forEach((doc) => {
        const funkoObj = new FunkoPop(doc.data().genre, doc.data().funkoData);
        funkoArr.push(funkoObj);
      });

      // genre matching if query is not a number
      let genreMatches = [];
      if (isNaN(query)) {
        genreMatches = funkoArr.filter((funko) =>
          funko.genre.toLowerCase().includes(query)
        );
      }
      if (genreMatches.length === 0) {
        genreMatches = `No funko pop genres with search: ${query}`;
      }

      // name & number matching
      const objToSearch = {
        notNullNameArr: [],
        notNullNumbArr: [],
        nameMatches: [],
        numbMatches: [],
      };

      funkoArr.forEach((funko) => {
        const genre = funko.genre;
        if (funko.funkoData) {
          const funkoDataArr = funko.funkoData;
          funkoDataArr.forEach((data) => {
            if (data.name) {
              objToSearch.notNullNameArr.push({
                funkoData: [data],
                genre: genre,
              });
            }
            if (data.number) {
              objToSearch.notNullNumbArr.push({
                funkoData: [data],
                genre: genre,
              });
            }
          });
        }
      });
      // find name that includes query
      objToSearch.notNullNameArr.forEach((funko) => {
        const genre = funko.genre;
        const name = funko.funkoData.filter((data) =>
          data.name.toLowerCase().includes(query)
        );
        if (Object.keys(name).length > 0) {
          objToSearch.nameMatches.push({
            genre,
            name,
          });
        }
      });
      // find number that matches query
      objToSearch.notNullNumbArr.forEach((funko) => {
        const genre = funko.genre;
        const number = funko.funkoData.filter((data) => data.number === query);
        if (Object.keys(number).length > 0) {
          objToSearch.numbMatches.push({
            genre,
            number,
          });
        }
      });

      if (objToSearch.nameMatches.length === 0) {
        objToSearch.nameMatches = `No funko pops found with search name: ${query}`;
      }
      if (objToSearch.numbMatches.length === 0) {
        objToSearch.numbMatches = `No funko pop numbers found with search: ${query}`;
      }

      const searchFinds = {
        genre: genreMatches,
        name: objToSearch.nameMatches,
        number: objToSearch.numbMatches,
      };

      res.send(searchFinds);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).send(error.message);
  }
};
```

If anyone is well suited in backend and knows more about firestore querying, please let me know!